# Parallel foreach loop fails when monitors are turned off

Tags: r, serialization, foreach, parallel-processing

This sounds crazy, but it has happened three times.  I have a foreach loop set up:

```
library(parallel)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

for(j in 1:length(start_times)) {
  ...

  cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1, outfile="status.txt")
  registerDoParallel(cl, cores = detectCores() - 1)

  assign(paste("master_data",j,sep=""),
     foreach(i = 1:nrow(start_points_data), .packages=c("doBy","plyr","fossil","geosphere","reshape","rgdal","sp","rgeos","spatialEco","maptools"), .combine=rbind) %dopar% {

    print(paste(Sys.time(), ": Starting ",i," of ",nrow(start_points_data)," locations.", sep=""))

    ...
  } )
stopCluster(cl)
}
```

(The reason the foreach loop is nested in another loop is because I thought this error was being caused by my process being too long.  So I split it up.)

I've scaled back my dataset for testing, and it has completed successfully several times while I've sat at the desk doing other things.  However, if I turn my computer monitors off, the process stops with this error:

```
Error in unserialize(socklist[[n]]) : error reading from connection
```

Each individual iteration of the code in the foreach loop takes less than a second per worker, and looking at the outfile, it's clear that processing stops within a minute of turning the monitors off, no matter how many times it's been through either the foreach loop or the parent for loop.

Is Windows trying to be smart by shutting something down when it senses the monitors have been turned off?

Comment: I don't really trust setting "outfile" to a filename because it doesn't work well to have the workers all writing to a single file. I think you're more likely to see an error message from a dying worker if you use `outfile=""`, and then run your program using Rterm from a "command prompt" window.

Comment: Clearly the monitors weren't the issue.  Just a case of high correlation, I think.

Answer (score 0):

First, thanks to Steve for the outfile tip.

The problem was with workers dying.  I implemented a `tryCatch()` that stops the current cluster and re-registers it.  Since output files are written after each successful completion of a parent loop, processing can just pick up where it left off based on the number of output files that exist.  A bit inelegant, but it seems to work.